# how does the histogram of optical flow work?

Tags: matlab, opencv, opticalflow

I surf the web for HOF implementation in matlab or openCV. Actually I wanted to know how to write their code in matlab. I learned something from the link bellow about HOG but I cannot find the same proper link for HOF or MBH. Is there any syntax for HOF in openCV?
http://www.learnopencv.com/histogram-of-oriented-gradients/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know about OpenCV, but find matlab implementations [here](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/juijling/index.php#page=software).

Comment: Thank you Stefan. This is a great help for me!

Comment: You can hook those functions up to my toolbox on [optical flow in Matlab](https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/44400-tutorial-and-toolbox-on-real-time-optical-flow) if you like. Its especially easy to do it on saved data with the toolbox, and relatively easy to modify it to calculate it on the fly in real-time